# The projection of a vector onto a vector subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $U = \{(x,y,z)  ∈ \Bbb R^3 :(2x-y+z=0 )\}$ a vector subspace in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Find the projection of vector $w$= ($1,0,-1$) onto subspace $U$ and prove that this vector (the projection) $∈$ $U$.

Comment: Then go forth and do what you've been told!

Comment: On top of the above, also remember to define what you mean by projection.